# Solve for $x$ so that the rank of the matrix is $2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

> Given $$M = \left(\matrix{
>               1 & 2 & 3 & { - 1} & 1       \cr 
>               3 & 2 & 1 & { - 1} & 1       \cr 
>               2 & 3 & 1 &     1  & 1       \cr 
>               5 & 5 & 2 &     0  & {2x + 1}\cr } \right) $$ solve for $x$ such that $\mbox{rank}(M)=2$

---

What I have tried here is to convert this to row echelon form, which is:
$$\left( {\matrix{
   1 & 2 & 3 & { - 1} & 1  \cr 
   0 & { - 4} & { - 8} & 2 & { - 2}  \cr 
   0 & 0 & { - 3} & {{5 \over 2}} & { - {1 \over 2}}  \cr 
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & {2x - 1}  \cr 
 } } \right)$$
It seems that this matrix cannot have the rank of 2, but can I prove it without converting the matrix to row echelon form? Thank you.

Comment: Did you mean “solve for **x**”? Anyway, if you know the “Minor method” to find the rank of a matrix I will post an answer. :)

Comment: @MatteoMenghini Yes, I do. I am looking forward to your answer

Comment: I think that @coudy below found a good answer which has the same idea behind.

Comment: Solve for $m$?!

Answer (score 1):

You can compute the determinant of $$\pmatrix{1 &2 &3 \cr 3 & 2 & 1\cr 2 & 3 & 1}.$$
It is non-zero, so there is no linear relation between the first three rows and the matrix must have rank 3 at least.